# Can we classify all primes in the set of candidates at a certain iteration of the prime number sieve?

Tags: number-theory

Consider the group $U(p_1\dots p_n)$, where $p_i$ is the $i^{th}$ prime.  For any pair of primes $p,q>p_n$, say that $p\sim q$ if and only if $p\equiv q\pmod{p_1\dots p_n}$.  Does this define an equivalence relation on the set of all primes greater than $p_n$?  If so, how many equivalence classes are there?  What's the size of each class?  Does there exist $r\in U(p_1\dots p_n)$ such that the equivalence class of $r$ is empty?

I made this one up, so if it's a dumb question, I am to blame.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your first question is yes, this is an equivalence relation.

For the second question, it follows from Dirichlet Theorem on arithmetic progressions that for each  $r \in U(p1...p_n)$ there are infinitely many prime in its class.

Comment: Okay, and so the number of classes is $\phi(p_1\dots p_n)$, right?  Thanks for answering the question.  I had no idea about Dirichlet's Theorem.  Very interesting.  Clearly I know almost nothing about number theory.

Comment: So it would be interesting to consider the classes for $p_1\dots p_n+1$ and $p_1\dots p_n-1$ in connection with twin primes.

Comment: @SpencerParkin The problem is that it probably doesn't help. There are infinitely many primes of the form $k p_1...p_n \pm 1$ but there is no way of telling if you can find one pair for the same $k$.